# Why I can not download GAE data? 302 error is returned

Tags: google-app-engine, appcfg

I used the following command to download my GAE data:

```
appcfg.py download_data --log_file=bulkloader.log --kind=MyKind --url=http://myappid.appspot.com/rmt_api --filename=myfilename --db_filename=MyKind_db.sql3 --result_db_filename=MyKind_result_db.sql3 --config_file=bulkloader.yaml
```

It worked well a few days ago, but yesterday it returned me `access_token is expired`. I manually deleted gae oauth files at `/Users/myuser/` (I am on OSX), but it didn't help - now I get the following output:

```
09:51 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader.log
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Error 302: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

I tried to add `--verbose` and `--noisy` parms, but nothing changed.

In result I can not download the data. Upload of the application `appcfg.py --update` works well.

It looks like GAE issue, but all such [issues](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12435) are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the thread became confused by users posting potentially-unrelated material. You should open a new ticket linking to that one, and we'll be happy to take a look. We monitor the relevant tags here on Stack Overflow and Serverfault, along with several Google Groups forums and code.google.com Public Issue Trackers (along with the various GitHub projects), so you'll be sure to get a quick response.